# Do I have to check the InvokeRequired and use the Invoke function with every control I want to update?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm writing a scheduler. It has a single form **frmMain**, which shows jobs that are currently running, and a history of job steps that have run. It has an object of class **Scheduler** that manages running new jobs. **Scheduler** keeps a collection class, **List** which contains objects of class **RunningJob**. **RunningJob** executes each step in turn through a series of sub-classes.

When a job is started, the **Scheduler** creates a new **BackgroundWorker** with the **DoWork**, **ProgressChanged** and **RunWorkerCompleted** methods setup with handlers that point back into the instance of **RunningJob**.

Each time a job/step starts/ends, one of these handers in **RunningJob** raises an appropriate event into **Scheduler** and **Scheduler** raises an appropriate event into **frmMain**. i.e.:

**frmMain** (1 instance) <---- **Scheduler** (1 instance) <---- **RunningJob.WorkerProgressChanged** (many instances)

The **RunningJob** executes correctly, but the reporting going up to the interface is not working correctly. Also any logging to files I do is suspect (I'm using a single function: **LogInfo** to do this). I have a number of questions:

1. When I use **InvokeRequired()** and **Invoke()** within **frmMain**, do I have to do this with every single control I want to update (there are several). Can I just check InvokeRequired() on one control and use Invoke on all of them based on that result.
2. Why bother checking **InvokeRequired()** at all and just use **Invoke()** every single time? It will make for simpler code.
3. There is only one instance of **Scheduler** and I am raising events to get execution back into it from each **Job**. I think this is part of the problem. How is multithreading handled doing this? Is there some sort of **InvokeRequired/Invoke** check I can do on the events before raising them? Can I raise events at all in this situation? I like events, rather than calling methods on the owner class, because it improves encapsulation. What is best practice here?
4. In general, if I'm calling a piece of code from many different threads, not necessarily to update a form, but just to perform some function (e.g. add a line of text to a file for logging purposes), how do I block one thread until the other has completed?

Comment: You should use it as often as you use bold type, never.  Code that updates the UI belongs in a RunWorkerCompleted event handler or a Task continuation that uses the correct scheduler.

Comment: Hi @Hans. Thanks for replying. Bold is for clarity, or at least for clarity for me. All the code that updates the UI is within the BackGroundWorker event handlers (unbolded, especially for you), but, those handlers raise events to GUI level. I'm unclear what you mean by Task continuation? Additionally there is only one instance  of the scheduler class, so by default it is the correct one.

Comment: When about everything is special then nothing is special.  Applies to this kind of code as well, InvokeRequired is very risky and a threading race bug waiting to happen.  When it does go wrong then you don't stand a chance to debug it.  Very important to segregate the slow code from the UI code, BackgroundWorker helps you do that.  You can google ".net task continuation" and TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() to learn more.

Comment: The BackgroundWorker's `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events are rised in the Thread that created the BackgroundWorker. No need to invoke there. Never try to update the UI from the `DoWork` event / `OnDoWork` method. Should you need to *invoke* the UI Thread - in other situations, unrelated to the BGW - use `BeginInvoke() ` instead of `InvokeRequired`/`Invoke`.